# What is this copper-looking wire on my light fixture?

Tags: electrical, wiring, lighting

I had an electrician install two hanging pendants over a kitchen island. The install went well and the pendants work fine.

However, after the install I've had an opportunity to look at the fixtures up close, I can't understand what this wire is. The light fixture hangs with a chain and has a typical-sized black cord which I assume is the main power for the pendant. However, there's a copper-colored wire which hangs along down with the chain and the black cord, which doesn't seem normal to me.

Any idea on what this is? I'd like to remove it, but I want to be sure what it is and if it's important first.

Here is a closeup of the copper-colored wire:
[image: The mysterious copper-colored wire closeup]

And here is a view of the full pendant:

[image: The hanging pendant with a copper wire intertwined with the chain and cord]

Comment: Give it some time, bare copped will darken by itself over time. Ever seen those matte black overhead wires trams and electric trains use? They were as shiny as your one when installed. (unless it's painted with clear paint)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I'm almost certain it is the ground wire. Do **not** remove it.

If you were to open the light fixture, there should be a screw where one end of the ground wire is attached. Then, mounted in the ceiling is a metal box through which is fed all the electrical wiring. There's a screw on the ceiling box that the other end of the ground wire is attached.

[image]

> Thank you. A natural follow-up question to this, since the original intent was to remove the distracting copper wire for aesthetic reasons, is: will the ground wire be less effective if it is painted or somehow covered to match the rest of the fixture?

Adding paint is essentially adding a layer of insulation to the wire. Since insulated wire still conducts electricity, a painted ground wire will be just as effective (i.e., conductive) as one that lacks an exterior coat of paint. You simply want to ensure that you do not paint over the location where it is attached to the screw on both ends (it needs metal-on-metal contact).

Comment: Is there a reason the fixture would have been built like this instead of using a three-conductor cord?

Comment: Yes, my question was _why_ a two-conductor cord was used.

Comment: It is most likely also a much easier change in the assembly line to add an extra wire like this than to setup the machines to handle a 3-conductor cord.

Comment: It's probably easier to buy a piece of black 3-wire cable and replace both the ground wire and the 2-wire cable than to remove the ground wire, paint it and reinsert it.

Comment: I think it was added by the electrician who installed it in order to make an old/imported fixture conform to new/local code.

Comment: You could replace the wire. It should be there but if you don't like they eye sore you could replace the wire with a coated one. There are no rules that say a ground wire needs to be bare (that I am aware of). Just make sure you do use one.

Comment: @Agent_L No, this arrangement is standard for lamps in the US.  Historically, lamp cords contained only two conductors (power and neutral) that went to each lamp socket.  When something goes wrong and the power touches the (commonly metal) lamp fixture, people get hurt.  Starting in the (someone help here with the decade)'s ground wires were added to ground the fixtures, but the same lamp socket arrangement was kept.  Many/most fixture makers never moved past this "temporary" workaround.  Perhaps someone else can give background as to why.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend removing or changing the wire.  It was designed to fit that fixture, the UL labs tested it, it should be safe far that fixture.  Rewiring it could potentially make it a fire hazard, the fixture might be bonded at multiple location along the wire and if missed could become a fire or electrocution hazard.

Comment: @JS. I understand the need for grounding, I was an electrician myself. But dealing with one 3-wire cable is always cheaper than dealing with 2 separate cables. That's why I understood it as last-minute refit. Unless it's part of the code that the grounding wire MUST be bare. Eg to try to ground every link of the chain. In that case painting or covering the ground wire would be against the code, must be recommended against and OP can't do anything but deal with it.

Comment: @Agent_L I meant to point out that that ground wire was likely not added by an electrician after the fact.  Nearly every light fixture you will find (at least at the home improvement stores I frequent) have an identical grounding wire.   It's cheesy, I know.  Heck, if you're interested in being right, look up that fixture.  If the wire's not in the box you'll have won all the internet points.

Comment: @JS. I believed you the first time you said it's standard practice, I was only trying to explain why I got it wrong. I'm trying to understand the reason this wire is bare.

Answer (score 11):

Yes it is a ground wire. It is required by more-recent codes.

They definitely can be unsightly.  Instead of trying to paint it, which will look awful, just replace it.  Some black-insulated, copper, 16 or 14 (or maybe even 18) AWG wire should do the trick quickly and easily.  There's no need to disturb the other wires, just run the new black wire in the place of the existing bare copper wire.

Comment: If you want to spend the time you can re-wire the entire lamp so it uses one wire for all 3 contact.  Make sure you get the hot-neutral-ground correct though, because it can have safely implications if you swap hot/neutral.

Comment: I WOULD NOT try to replace this ground wire. It is likely to be riveted in place, or connected to a large ring terminal, which will not be easy to replace or duplicate. .......Just leave  it.

Answer (score 1):

It is a frame ground. It's bonded to the metal of the fixture so that if a bare live wire touches the metal it trips the breaker. If it wasn't there and a live wire was touching, nothing would happen; until you went to change or clean the fixture. Then you become the source to ground and will get a zap.

A frame ground is a safety requirement and is not to be removed. After a week you won't even notice it anymore.

Answer (score 0):

This is a ground wire. And it looks like the ground was added later or like only the cage is grounded.

Remove it **only if** you are replacing the 2-wire cord with at least 3-wire cord.

With 4-wire cord you can light the bulbs independently (power1, power2, (shared) neutral, ground).

Also be sure that all metal parts are grounded.

Comment: This ground was not added later. Almost every chain hung fixture comes like this nowadays. Also, the term "common" is not really an accurate or accepted term. The term "neutral" is the industry standard.

Comment: @SpeedyPetey: Surely there must be some adjective that clarifies the neutral is shared between the two powers rather than just calling it neutral? Or at the very least isn't this a reasonable use of the term? Even if not a technical electrical term I'd have thought it was meaningful (and indeed I worked out what it meant).

Comment: Honestly, I have no idea what the comment means. One of the reasons the term is not used for a neutral is that the term "common" is used in 3-way switching setups, so it can be confusing. This does not change the fact that it is incorrectly used by lay folks pretty regularly.

Comment: @Chris: Neutral and common are not the same thing.  "Neutral" implies a balance (or lack) of voltage potential; "common" does not.  Not all circuits use or have a neutral, but what about a "common"?  It's not as subtle as the difference between groundED conductor and groundING conductor.

Comment: @SpeedyPetey English is not my mother tongue, I hope that "shared neutral" will be more leading to the idea I wanted to share. It looks like "optional extra" to me, which needn't be true. If I were to make it on my own I'd use 3-wire cord or 4-wire cord.

Comment: Ah. I appreciate that neutral and common are not interchangeable but the original wording of "common neutral" suggested to me a neutral that was shared by both. It sounds like common has a technical definition that I was not aware of though that was causing the amibuity/confusion/whatever (I'm a lay folk - guilty as charged!) :)