# How should a cut chandelier wire be repaired?

Tags: electrical, wiring, light-fixture

The wire in our chandelier is cut and spliced between the fixture and the ceiling. The chandelier is currently being supported by the wires and not the chain. Does the wire need to be completely replaced?

[image: Wires connected and covered by electrical tape]

[image: Chain clearly to long for the wire currently]

Comment: I stripped the rant and unrelated commentary from your post. That's not what we're concerned with here. You'll get your answer and can then deal with the electrician as you see fit. For help with legal or contractual issues, consult other websites.

Answer (score 14):

Replace the cord. Legal situation will vary by country, but in NZ I would cite ASNZS 3000:2007:

> 3.7.2.6 Mechanical stress
>
> All cables and conductors shall be installed so that there is no undue mechanical stress on any connection.

> 3.7.2.8: Flexible Cords
>
> Joints shall not be made in flexible cords.

Answer (score 5):

The real issue is that the lamp appears to be suspended on the electrical cable. That's not OK.

There's a chain, and there's a metal wire; the weight should be suspended on one of these. There's clearly a lot of slack on the chain, and there's a bit of slack on the steel wire. I'm not sure which is supposed to support the weight. Make an educated guess there.

After that, either use a longer electric cable, or shorten the mechanical wire/chain, so that there's slack on electrical cable.

Ideally you'd replace the electric cable, both for reliability (and therefore safety) and aesthetics.

Since this is home improvement, you can use something as simple as "sugar cube" connecting blocks or shrink connectors or spring wire connectors, or an inline junction box, or even twist the wires and cover with electric tape (least safe).

In summary: supporting the weight is the problem, use common sense.

Comment: That bare wire is the ground wire.  (See e.g. https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/95247/what-is-this-copper-looking-wire-on-my-light-fixture).  The chain is meant to support the weight.